# Android Notification Area Customization

Tags: java, android, notifications, push-notification

I don't know whether this question get minus points, but I searched every where and my last resort is stackoverflow.

I need to add five buttons to notification area in horizontally. And each button I need to add even listener. I know it is possible to do with RemoteViews. But I never seen anyone adding event listener to each element.

These are the references if anyone need to refer.

[Notifications Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomExpandedView)

[How to create a custom notification on android](http://www.framentos.com/android-tutorial/2012/02/20/how-to-create-a-custom-notification-on-android/)

[SlidingDrawer API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can add 5 anonymous listeners, or a single named listener.

Anonymous:

```
Button b1 = new Button(...);
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // first listener's code goes here
    }
});

Button b2 = new Button(...);
b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // second listener's code goes here
    }
});
...
```

named is much the same, but contains a switch statement to differentiate what happens:

```
View.OnClickListener myListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String buttonTitle = ((Button)v).getText();
        if ("title1".equals(buttonTitle)) {
            // do things for the first button's click
        } else if ("title2".equals(buttonTitle)) {
            // do things for the second button's click
        }
        ...
    }
});
...
```